# Answering certain input answers with print commands in python

Tags: python, if-statement, input, printing

I am coding in python code to give you a link to website/video and I want my code to answer each input with a print command saying you picked __ here is where you can watch ___ link:

Here is my code it has an error I  can't work it out

```
import time

print ("Please put in anime yo``u would like to watch we have")
time.sleep(0.5)
Anime = input("Naruto,DragonBall:")
if input == "Naruto"
print("Test")
```

Comment: I'd guess you mean a *syntax* error, because your `if` block is wrong, but please note a [mre] is required. See https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F for appropriate entry points to the language.

Comment: The value you wrote in input is saved in your case in the variable `Anime`. So your if statement should be `if Anime == "Naruto"`

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

print ("Please put in anime you would like to watch we have")
time.sleep(0.5)
Anime = input("Naruto,DragonBall:")
if Anime == "Naruto":
    print("Test")
```

Comment: How do I add multiple if Anime statements